# php str_replace

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$cl_posturl = "https://post.craigslist.org/".str_replace('"','',$result[FORM][0][ACTION]);

echo $cl_posturl."<br>\n";
```

It if returning

post.craigslist.org//sdo/S/ctd/csd/x/**9FMALgak4Td10Bol/XRk68**

it use to return

post.craigslist.org//sdo/S/ctd/csd/x/

how can I modify the code to return it without those 2 last paths

Comment: Probably you're getting incorrect data in $result[FORM][0][ACTION], have you try to print that array?

Answer (score 1):

Hey broken this into a few steps for easy reading, but it can be condensed into a single call once you understand it.

```
$initialString = '/sdo/S/ctd/csd/x/9FMALgak4Td10Bol/XRk68';
$removeOneLevel = substr($initialString, 0, strrpos($initialString, '/'));
$removeSecondLevel = substr($removeOneLevel, 0, strrpos($removeOneLevel, '/'));

$finalUrl = "https://post.craigslist.org".str_replace('"','', $removeSecondLevel);
echo $finalUrl . "\n";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh BTW, I used $initialString rather than $result[FORM][0][ACTION] so that I could test from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Why did the value of 
$result[FORM][0][ACTION]

change from
/sdo/S/ctd/csd/x/
to
/sdo/S/ctd/csd/x/9FMALgak4Td10Bol/XRk68
?

I would first understand why that happened.

Comment: [FORM] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => "postingForm"
                    [ACTION] => "/sdo/S/ctd/csd/x/vayNgFunjY5mPr9C/iNp0B"
                    [METHOD] => "post"
                    [ENCTYPE] => "multipart/form-data"
                )

        )

The Action value is now returning that additional data. but when posting to it we get a 404

Comment: try: $cl_posturl = "post.craigslist.org/".$result[FORM][0][ACTION]; echo $cl_posturl."<br>\n"; and post it here